# Powershell offset number in name of multiple files by a constant

Tags: powershell, numbers, addition, filenames, offset

I have multiple files from camera with names "00010001", "00010002", etc. Those are multiple file types (JPG, CR2, xmp, MOV) in one folder (lets say C:\camera).

I need to add 10000 to number in all file names, so it becomes "00020001", "00020002", etc. I guess this could be done with a simple script in powershell, but I have absolute no experience with it. I would be very grateful if someone helped me with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code should also handle files in subfolders of 'C:\Camera', you can use the `-Recurse` and `-Include` parameters:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Camera' -File -Include '*.JPG','*.CR2','*.XMP','*.MOV' -Recurse) | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d{8}' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D8}{1}' -f ([int]$_.BaseName + 10000), $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

If however this should NOT go any deeper that the root folder 'C:\Camera', then do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Camera' -File) | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d{8}' -and $_.Extension  -match '\.(JPG|CR2|XMP|MOV)$' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D8}{1}' -f ([int]$_.BaseName + 10000), $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Once you are satisfied the code would create the new filenames as you wish, remove the safety switch `-WhatIf`

**Explanation:**

- Get the files in the folder that have BaseNames consisting of 8 digits `($_.BaseName -match '\d{8}'`) and that have an extension of either `JPG`, `.CR2`, `.XMP` or `.MOV`
- Convert that BaseNaem into an interger number and add 10000
- Reassemble the file name with the `-f` format operator, where the template string `{0:D8}{1}` makes sure all (new) numbers are prefixed with zeroes up to 8 digits

Comment: I'm finding that if I run this, Get-ChildItem is finding the same files infinite times and keeps adding 10000 to ihem over and over.  Looks perfectly fine when doing -WhatIf but does not work as expected without.  I think the answer is to grab the collection of files first into a variable and then pipe the $variable to the rename-command.

Comment: @Daniel Well spotted. I have tested with just two files and that went fine.. I have now surrounded the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with brackets, so the code finishes that complete before spitting out through the pipeline.